# Unity metadate too big

Tags: unity-game-engine, metadata

I ask this here because nobody helped me on unity's forum. In my project I have a metadata file. It becomed big after I put 300mb assets in my project (sprites). I delet all assets but it doesn't work. Any way to safety clear it? If I cant I think I will delet the project beacouse it is too big. And I cant find any helpfull answer

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/642816/assets-folder-312mb-librarymetadata-folder-1347mb.html

Comment: So I will delet my project

Comment: Try:) after making the backup

Comment: How can I make a safe backup? everything I find is post like: I backup my project and everything is gone